# Xamarin forms - Underline Label with binding

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learnig xamarin, I would like to bind some propreties to a label

I have manage to do with IsVisible , TextColor & Text porprety with model like this :

```
public Color MyLabelColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#ff6465");
public string LabelText { get; set; }
public bool LabelIsVisibleOrNot { get; set; } = false;

And bind the like this: 
IsVisible="{Binding MyLabelColor}"
Text="{Binding LabelText}"
TextColor="{Binding MyLabelColor }"
```

I would like to bind the label proprety : `TextDecorations="Underline, Strikethrough"`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing Jason's code like this：

```
 public TextDecorations Decoration
    {
        get
        {
            return TextDecorations.Underline | TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
        }
    }

  <Label Text="{Binding LabelText}" TextDecorations="{Binding Decoration}" />
```

By the way, when you use binding, don't forget to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** to notify data changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[TextDecorations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.textdecorations?view=xamarin-forms) is an enum

```
public TextDecorations Decoration { get { 
  return TextDecorations.Underline & TextDecorations.Strikethrough; } }


<Label Text="{Binding Subject}" TextDecorations="{Binding Decoration}" />
```

Comment: TextDecorations.Strikethrough && TextDecorations.Underline is not working because of "&&" or "&"

Comment: it should be a single &

Comment: What does “not working” mean?  Are you getting an error or exception?  What specifically is it doing or not doing?

Comment: The propreties are not apply to the label